# Understanding Weights shape of an LSTM cell with 2-D input tensor

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, mnist

I am building a simple LSTM model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences = False, input_shape = (8, 8)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = adam, metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Here, my input is a ndarray of shape (8,8). From the trained model out of this network, when I dump out the weights, I get the values as:

```
print(model.layers.layer[0].get_weights[0].shape) # W [W_i, W_f, W_c, W_o]
print(model.layers.layer[0].get_weights[1].shape) # U
print(model.layers.layer[0].get_weights[2].shape) # b
```

Outputs:

```
(8, 40)
(10, 40)
(40,)
```

W is a combined matrix of `W_i`, `W_f`, `W_c` and `W_o` each with `(8, 10)`. But this doesn't match with the equation:

```
f_t = sigmoid( W_f * x + U_f * h_{t-1} + b_f )
```

If I take just the matrix dimension of the above equation, it goes like this:

```
W_f' * x + U_f' * h_{t-1} + b_f 
    --> [10, 8] x [8, 8] + [10, 10] x [10, 1] + [10, 1] 
    --> [10, 8] + [10, 1] + [10, 1]
```

So looking at the above equation, it seems the shape of `X(input_tensor)` is incorrect. Only vector input shape seems to be fitting the above equation. Can someone help me understand the above equation with input shape as 2-D?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you mentioned is for computing the output for `t`-th timestep. Therefore, only the input at timestep `t` is used (i.e. `x_t`) and not all the inputs (i.e. `x`):

```
f_t = sigmoid( W_f * x_{t} + U_f * h_{t-1} + b_f )
```

As a result we would have:

```
W_f' * x + U_f' * h_{t-1} + b_f 
    --> [10, 8] x [8, 1] + [10, 10] x [10, 1] + [10, 1] 
    --> [10, 1] + [10, 1] + [10, 1]
    --> [10, 1] # output at timestep t
```

And this is in harmony with what LSTM layers are meant to do: they get the input at timestep `t` and give an output based on the that input and the state resulted from processing the first to `(t-1)`-th timesteps.

Comment: But the `input_shape` is (8,8). Does it mean the entire input is getting processed in 8 `t` time step?

Comment: @RachitAgrawal That's right. The input to LSTM is a timeseries/sequence; therefore, it has an input shape of `(n_timesteps, n_features)`. An input shape of `(8,8)` means that each training sample consists of 8 timesteps where each timesteps is a feature vector of length 8.

Comment: Ok. Got it. missed the interpretation of `input_shape = (batch, timesteps, features)`. Thanks.